# How to serve proper user age-based ads with AdMob?

Tags: java, android, ios, admob

As we know there are different content ad ratings from G for children up to MA for adults.

Now If I have an app that is PEGI 3, I would like to display G ads if a young user is using my app, but if an adult is using my app I would like to display him MA ads as they are better paid.
But how do I know which user is using the app, a child or an adult? What is the standard way of doing it?

Comment: You would have to make the ad rating match the app rating. You can't really know the age of the user.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 Could you please clarify what exactly the "app rating" means in case of Android app? Is it PEGI rating or ESRB rating (cause they are different) or any other? Which rating should I match exactly?

Comment: @Paulw11 I guess you are right, but I do not understand this policy. How is knowing the age of the user while using the app different from knowing the age of the user while watching and installing the app on Play Store?

Comment: After giving it some more thought, I guess the answer is there is no difference. There is just no point in deciding on runtime.